# Is there a possibility to group coincident lines to evaluate line "density"?

Tags: python, math, geometry

## **Objective**

Starting from a line soup with many overlying lines. Group these coincident lines and sum the number of lines. Divide this sum to the highest sum in the assembly to get the relative amount. Use this relative amount as a measurement for the line density.

## **State of work**

One possibility that comes to my mind is to create a "Line" Class (or use shapely LineString) to calculate the distance between line pairs. In a coincident case, P_1 and P_2 of line_i are on line_j. For the application, a small tolerance for the coincidence would be required.
In this brute force approach, many many loops have to be done which can cause performance issues (I guess) for larger assemblies. Target number range of lines is 50.000 - 150.000.

[image: Line Coincidence]

## **Problem**

Currently, a smart approach is missing to do this task, either to

- Identify coincident line pairs
- And to build a smart structure containing this information to reduce the number of lines to the most significant ones with a measured density value

The resulting reduced set of lines shall be used for constructing polygons.

Unfortunately, I do not have an exemplary data set since I am already theoretically struggling. As soon as I have built an exemplary data set, I will put it online here.

Below, there is an example of a segment of the process. I have an approximated polygon represented by multiple lines. I only want to get the most "important" ones to rebuild the "most important" polygon from it. In the figure, one can see that l6 and l7 are there only once, so l8/l2 are preferred.

[image: Line segments]

Comment: To get an idea of the data set, you can plot all lines with some small alpha.

Answer (score 4):

Represent lines using rho-theta equation.

```
dx = x2 - x1  
dy = y2 - y1
L = Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
Dis = dx*y1 - dy*x1
SD = Sign(Dis)
rho = SD * Dis / L   // always poitive
theta = atan2(-SD*dx, SD*dy)
```

Fill 2D table containing some discrete set of angles and rho's like [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) accumulator.

For example, make angle step 1°, so 360 rows and some hundred columns for reasonable rho range. For every line increment value of `A[theta][rho]` using rounding to the closest integer indices.

Then check what cell has the largest amount of votes - in describes a set of close lines.

Note that this method is much faster than Hough transform because it works with ready-to-use lines, it is linear against number of lines and cell count depends on needed precision, while Hough works with points and fills the whole trajectory in rho-theta space for every point.

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you! I will check it as soon as I found some spare time

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is the following: (First, is there already a method to convert n lines to the rho-theta representation?) Second: A rho theta representation also represents start and end point of the lines. Would it recognize a coincidence like the one shown in the figure above? But well, I think I will get it when I am testing it

Comment: What method? Just calculate rho and theta from your representation. Formula added. Rho-theta describes infinite lines, not line segments.

Comment: Thanks for your support already! That the reason for my question. I guess that the infinite lines statement does depict an obstacle. In my geometry, two lines which are colinear but not coincident, depict different geometry segments, thus lines. calculating the rho-theta equation would identify them as a potential line pair. I guess I have to specify my question and add an image

Comment: You can try to separate lines into cells, then compare segment positions for lines in the same cell only. If direction distribution is random, this approach might accelerate.

Comment: Thank you MBo. I set up the houghes transform matrix and voted for the lines. However, I still do not know if I can or how I can use the result due to above discussed issues. What do you mena by separate lines into cells? I think this exceeds my intelligence. The only thing that comes to my mind would be to discretize the plane using pixels, add vote to each pixel if the line contains the pixel. Afterwards, mask the resulting image to get the most important pixels and recreate lines from it. But somehow, this does not seem attractive to me

Comment: What information is available for you - lines or pixels??  By separation I mean the next - every cell in rho-theta table refers to a bunch of alike lines (almost concident). You can compare every line only with lines in the same cell (perhaps in neighbor cells), not with all lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208104/discussion-between-bennys-and-mbo).