# Group of geometric lines to raster image with density

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry, rasterizing

## **Objective**

Polygons from line soup with density information (which equals the number of line occurences)

## **State of work**

Started from a completely geometric point in :
[Is there a possibility to group coincident lines to evaluate line "density"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276828/is-there-a-possibility-to-group-coincident-lines-to-evaluate-line-density)

Since I do not see any reasonable solution there, the trick might be to switch to rasterization and from the rastered image back to geometric lines/polygons.
Some keywords I found so far:

- Bresenham's line algorithm
- Rasterio package
- From raster to polygons : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons

## **Problem & Questions**

In some cases, e.g. 1000 lines are coincident, meaning that this contour is important. In other cases, only 100-50 lines are building another contour and are coincident, meaning that this contour is not important.

1. For this reason, I would like to create a raster image/matrix from these lines where the pixels/matrix entries contain the density. Is there any way to achieve this?
2. It is possible that contour is not closed and/or that there is more than 1 polygon represented. Is there any algorithm that builds some kind of "least common multiple" polygons and closes open contours by simply connecting it to the "next line"?